# Gephi 0.9.1 Twitter Streaming Importer: collects tweets very slowly

Tags: gephi

I just installed the Twitter Streaming Importer plugin in my Gephi. I tried it out but it's very slow in collecting tweets. It works but it's slow. It took 5 minutes to import 4 minutes of tweets filtered on the word "innovation". It sounds too much no?

Answer (score 1):

The `Twitter Streaming Importer` is as the word suggests a *streaming* importer. This means that it monitors Twitter for **NEW** tweets, i.e. tweets meeting the search criteria (tag, user, etc.) that are posted **after** you started monitoring. In that regard 4 tweets in 5 minutes sounds very reasonable.

On the other hand, if you want to collect historical tweets, you need to collect them through a library or a software that uses the Twitter Search API. [NodeXL](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/) is such a software plus there are a bunch of libraries for each programming language, e.g. [tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/) for Python, `twitteR` for R, etc.